# java, расшифровка данных

Tags: java, криптография

Есть класс шифрования/дешифрования строки.

**функция шифрования:**

```
public static String DESEncrypt(String datasource, String password) {
    String result = datasource;
    if (datasource != null) {
        try {
            if (!datasource.isEmpty()) {
                SecretKey securekey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(password.substring(0, 8).getBytes(Hex.DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME)));
                AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivkey);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(1, securekey, iv);
                result = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(datasource.getBytes(Hex.DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME)), 0);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.i("@error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**функция дешифрования:**

```
public static String DESDecrypt(String src, String password) {
    String result = src;
    if (src == null) {
        return result;
    }

    if (src.isEmpty()) {
        return result;
    }

    byte[] item = password.substring(0, 8).getBytes();
    try {
        DESKeySpec item2 = new DESKeySpec(item);
        SecretKey securekey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(item2);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return password.substring(0, 8);
    /*AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivkey);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(2, securekey, iv);
      return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(src)));*/        
}
```

интересует меня функция дешифрования, при ее запуске я вижу ошибку на строке

`SecretKey securekey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(item2);`

господа знатоки, подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

я специалист в области php,mysql.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException

Comment: Unhandled exception type InvalidKeySpecException

Comment: Unhandled exception type InvalidKeyException

Comment: Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что вам требуется установить расширение для работы с криптографией JCE [скачать](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html)

Comment: 1) Вообще то начиная с JDK 5 (по-моему) JCE уже входит в состав JDK и не требует специальной установки

2) Код все равно не будет работать, потому что при расшифровке и дешифровке должен использоваться один и тот же ключ, а ТС генерирует каждый раз новый.

Comment: @Barmaley отчасти вы правы, но не совсем, я ссылался, на дополнение для jdk 7, которое не является его частью. Данное дополнение позволяет использовать шифры с неограниченной длинной ключа, что в стандартной версии запрещено, ввиду законодательства США.

Comment: Ну может быть. Я все равно не пользуюсь JCE так что особо не слежу за этим

Comment: Кстати, судя по коду ТС использует Android... - может с этим связано?

Comment: Скорее всего, отсюда и отсутствие шифра. Потому что тот что использует автор явно указан в javadoc, и его никак не может не быть.